# Python tkinter frame canvas, widget Entry resize

Tags: python, tkinter, resize

I have problem. I'm using tkinter and python 2.7. How can I get a change in the length of the widget after resizing the window? I have two widgets:

Entry1 (column = 0) and Entry2 (column = 1)

Entry1 has a fixed width. Entry2 should fill the rest of the width. Unfortunately, it doesn't work.

Is there any way of doing this?

Many thanks in advance.

Code:

```
from Tkinter import *
import ttk

root = Tk()

root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

notebook = ttk.Notebook(root)
tab = Frame(notebook)
notebook.add(tab, text = "Tab 1")
notebook.grid(row=0,column=0, sticky="NSEW")

tab.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight =1)
tab.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

canvas_tab = Canvas(tab, width=500, height=100)
scroll_tab = Scrollbar(tab, command = canvas_tab.yview)

canvas_tab.config(yscrollcommand=scroll_tab.set)
scroll_tab.grid(row=0, column = 1, sticky = "NSE")

canvas_tab.grid(row=0, column = 0, sticky = "NSEW")
canvas_tab.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

frame = Frame(canvas_tab)
frame.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)

Entry1 = Entry(frame, text = "", width=20, justify = CENTER)
Entry1.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
Entry1.insert(0, 'Entry 1')

Entry2 = Entry(frame, text = "", justify = CENTER)
Entry2.grid(row = 0, column = 1, sticky = "NSEW")
Entry2.insert(0, 'Entry 2')

def configure(event):
    canvas_tab.itemconfig(root, width=event.width)

canvas_tab.create_window((0,0), anchor=NW, window=frame)
frame.update_idletasks()
canvas_tab.config(scrollregion = frame.bbox("all"))
canvas_tab.bind('<Configure>', configure)
root.mainloop()
```

[Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BXUP7.png)

Answer (score 0):

When we use 'place' instead of 'grid', it can be done using the relative height and relative width parameters.

This works:

```
Entry2=Entry(root,width=10)
Entry2.place(relheight=.2,relwidth=.45,relx=.5,rely=.28)
Entry2.insert(0, 'Entry 2')
```

Place is generally considered very tedious though. (You'll have to manually alter the relx and rely parameters to fix it's relative position.)